# AWS Instances Name tag update

Tags: amazon-web-services, tagging

There is a critical and Time eating task has been assigned to me in my project. In AWS we have 2.5k EC2 instances in the us-east region. In that around 2k Instance name is NA(blank). So In the same row need to pick the column(VOLUME_ID's) value and keep it as Instance's name. I need to do this for all Instances which are all blank so I need a script(maybe in python, etc...). Need help. Please let me know if any additional info required. Thanks in advance.

Please Note: I have AWS CLI access with Access key and secret key.

Comment: I somehow found out how to do it using boto (AWS SDK). But I need to know how to assign the value of VOLUME_ID to NAME value which is blank.

Comment: I completed the task by myself. Thanks!